# bring the millennium in our lifetime

Tags: meaning

What does the part **"bring the millennium in our lifetime"** mean?

> Our pastor said that we can **bring the millennium in our lifetime** if we treat each other with a spirit of generosity and forgiveness.

Comment: Make sure you tell us what your dictionary says about any unusual words.  I'd expect a good question to include what you think "millennium" means.

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked up the word "millennium" it means "The prophesied 1000 year reign of Christ". ([Wiktionary sense 2](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/millennium#Noun))

This is a technical use by Christians, and is in addition to the normal sense of "a period of 1000 years)

The pastor is saying that if we love each other, we can cause Christ to return to Earth as predicted in the book of Revelation of the Bible.